# Centering with unknown width

Tags: html, css, centering

I normally center elements with dynamic widths with the following code.

```
.horz-vert-center {
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top:50%;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 }
```

The problem is the element will resize earlier than I want. eg. A menu goes to two lines when it could still fit on one:

[image]

I don't really understand this, if I am using % values, why do the margins not continue to get smaller?

Demo here:
https://codepen.io/garethj/pen/LWdaRr

Comment: it works fine for me.

Comment: keep resizing - it folds before it should

Comment: You could give it a value of `display:inline-flex`?

Comment: On my console- it is breaking when it reaches just over 468px. This is becuse the position absolute is set to 50% and the width of the text and assoc margins is just over 234px. The translate makes it seem that it should fit in but in reality all this is doing is moving the ul to the side - not altering its witdth / margins. Would recommend the solutions posted here. or alternatively use margin:auto.

Comment: right - because the element is kept at 50% width, which is not what I want. I want my element to be centered no matter what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just another approach using "Theodore K." snippet

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nhgsvth3/)

```css
.horz-vert-center {
  width:50%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  text-align: center;
}
.horz-vert-center li{
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

*{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

```html
<ul class="horz-vert-center">
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Work</li>
  <li>Blog</li>
  <li>Journal</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: works if you remove "width:50%". This does not work if you are dealing  with non text elements.

Comment: It does now answers the requirements, since the width is 50% (and the text will collapse just line the code in the question, AND it is not vertically centered (like in the question...)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `white-space:nowrap;` on the `ul` and `display: inline-block; float: none;` on the `li` seems to do the trick.

```css
.horz-vert-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.horz-vert-center li{
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

body {background:#ccc}
*{margin:0;padding:0;font-family:arial;font-size:20px}
ul {list-style-type:none}
li {float:left;margin-right:10px}
li:last-child {margin-right:0;}
```

```html
<ul class="horz-vert-center">
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Work</li>
  <li>Blog</li>
  <li>Journal</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you nowrap does work for my example. If it was not text I guess it would not work. How do I center with say 5% margins ? I guess my code is saying always keep the element at 50% width?